# Is the htmlunit "WARNING: CSSValue '0\0' has to be a 'px', 'em', '%', 'mm', 'ex', or 'pt' value." really just a warning?

Tags: htmlunit

I'm trying to load a web page with htmlunit 2.33 and my app displays the above CSS warning in a seemingly endless, repeating list.

I'm specifying FIREFOX_60.

I've tried setting the "silent" css error handler, but that doesn't help.

```
wc.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());
```

I'm not sure that setting the log level to OFF is the right answer, either.

It looked to me like the htmlunit library was stuck in a loop.  Sure enough, when I let the page complete, I was presented with this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the        
 UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue; please open one in the HtmlUnit bug tracker or on github and provide all the details you have (complete stack traces, souce code, url of the page your are testing and so on). If i'm able to reproduce i can fix it.